# MacVim can't load YouCompleteMe which is compiled by clang and installed by vundle

Tags: vim, macvim

I installed newest MacVim in Yosemite 10.10.2 with Vundle Plugin.I also downloaded the YCM by git-clone.I have compiled it by clang.But when I open the MacVim and editor cpp file,It can't work at all.What confuse me is than no YCM command is work well.